# How do i reprint menu using do-while

Tags: java

```
package mathloops3;

import java.util.*; import java.util.Random;

public class Program3 {

 public static void main(String args[])
 {
     //======================================================================
     //Input
     //======================================================================

         Scanner kb = new Scanner( System.in );

         System.out.println("Please enter a non-negative integer: ");
         int num1 = kb.nextInt();
             while ( num1 == 0 || num1 <= 0 )
             {
                 System.out.println("Please enter a non-negative integer: ");
                 num1 = kb.nextInt();
             }

     //======================================================================
     //Menu
     //======================================================================

         System.out.println("Please make a choice");
         System.out.println("0 Print the number");
         System.out.println("1 Determine if the number is odd or even");
         System.out.println("2 Find half of the number");
         System.out.println("3 Find the reciprocal of the number");
         System.out.println("4 Raise the number to the power of 5");
         System.out.println("5 Raise the number to a power of 5");
         System.out.println("6 Generate 20 random numbers between 0 and the number");
         System.out.println("7 Find the sum of 0 up to your number");
         System.out.println("8 Find the factorial of the number");
         System.out.println("9 find the square root of the number");
         System.out.println("10 Find the square root of the number");
         System.out.println("11 Determine whether the number is prime");         
         System.out.println("12 Exit the Program");

     //======================================================================
     //Menu Choice Switch
     //======================================================================

         System.out.println("Please enter choice: ");
         int menuChoice = kb.nextInt(); 

         switch (menuChoice)
         {
             case 0: System.out.println("Yor number is " + num1 ); break;

             case 1: 
                 if ( num1 %2 == 0)
                    System.out.println( num1 + " is even!");
                 else
                     System.out.println( num1 + " is odd!");
                 break;

             case 2: System.out.println("Half of " + num1 +  " is " + num1 / 2); break;

             case 3: System.out.println("The reciprocal of " + num1 + " is 1/" + num1 ); break;

             case 4: System.out.println( num1 + " to the 5th power is " 
                     + (int)java.lang.Math.pow(num1,5)); break;

             case 5:
                 double t = 1;
                 double b = num1;
                 double exponent = 5;
                 for ( int i = 1; i<=exponent; i++ )
                     t = t*b;
                 System.out.println(num1 + " to the 5th power is " + (int)t);
                 break;

             case 6: 
                 List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                 int  numberOfNumbersYouWant = 20; // This has to be less than 11
                 Random random = new Random();

                     do
                     {
                         int next = random.nextInt(20);
                         if (!numbers.contains(next))
                         {
                             numbers.add(next);
                             System.out.println(next);
                         }
                     } while (numbers.size() < numberOfNumbersYouWant);
                 break;

             case 7: 
                 for(int i = 1; i < num1; i++) 
                 {
                     System.out.println(i);
                 }
                 break;

             case 8:
                 int i,fact=1;  
                 int number=num1;//It is the number to calculate factorial    
                 for(i=1;i<=number;i++)
                     {    
                         fact=fact*i;    
                     }    
                 System.out.println("Factorial of "+number+" is: "+fact);  
                 break;

             case 9:
                 int sqrt = num1;
                 System.out.println("The square root of " + num1 + " is " + (int)Math.sqrt(sqrt));
                 break;

             case 10: 
                 int sqrtloop=1;
                 int iterations=1;
                 int curSum = 0;
                     do 
                     {
                         sqrtloop+=2; iterations++; curSum +=sqrtloop;

                     } while (curSum + sqrtloop < num1 );
                         System.out.println("The square root of " + num1 + " is " + iterations);
                 break;

             case 11: 
                 int num = num1;
                 boolean flag = false;
                 for(int prime = 2; prime <= num/2; ++prime)
                 {
                     // condition for nonprime number
                     if(num % prime == 0)
                     {
                         flag = true;
                         break;
                     }
                 }

                 if (!flag)
                     System.out.println(num + " is a prime number.");
                 else
                     System.out.println(num + " is not a prime number.");
                 break;

             case 12: 
                 System.out.println("Thank you, Bye-Bye!");
                 System.exit(0);
                 break;
         }//end switch
         do              //details: this is where i am trying out different things with the do-while but i just cant seem to get it
right
             {    
                 if ( menuChoice != 12)
                 {
                     System.out.println("Please make a choice");
                     System.out.println("0 Print the number");
                     System.out.println("1 Determine if the number is odd or even");
                     System.out.println("2 Find half of the number");
                     System.out.println("3 Find the reciprocal of the number");
                     System.out.println("4 Raise the number to the power of 5");
                     System.out.println("5 Raise the number to a power of 5");
                     System.out.println("6 Generate 20 random numbers between 0 and the number");
                     System.out.println("7 Find the sum of 0 up to your number");
                     System.out.println("8 Find the factorial of the number");
                     System.out.println("9 find the square root of the number");
                     System.out.println("10 Find the square root of the number");
                     System.out.println("11 Determine whether the number is prime");         
                     System.out.println("12 Exit the Program");
                 }
             }while (menuChoice != menuChoice);
 }//end main }//end class
```

I cant seem to reprint the menu, I've tried multiple things but I've come to the conclusion that it has to be a `do-while` loop but it will either run forever, or it will print once and then terminate the program.

Comment: If I were you I would write down on a piece of paper the high level flow of what you want to happen e.g. Show menu -> Take Input -> Process Input -> Show Menu and then put each of these steps into methods, then tell us what is not working, of course some steps could even be placeholders whilst you get the other stuff to work

Comment: `while (menuChoice != menuChoice)` how could this ever be?

Answer (score 0):

Guess this would help:

```
do         
                 {    
                         //your switch case should be here


                         System.out.println("Please make a choice");
                         System.out.println("0 Print the number");
                         System.out.println("1 Determine if the number is odd or even");
                         System.out.println("2 Find half of the number");
                         System.out.println("3 Find the reciprocal of the number");
                         System.out.println("4 Raise the number to the power of 5");
                         System.out.println("5 Raise the number to a power of 5");
                         System.out.println("6 Generate 20 random numbers between 0 and the number");
                         System.out.println("7 Find the sum of 0 up to your number");
                         System.out.println("8 Find the factorial of the number");
                         System.out.println("9 find the square root of the number");
                         System.out.println("10 Find the square root of the number");
                         System.out.println("11 Determine whether the number is prime");         
                         System.out.println("12 Exit the Program");
                         menuChoice =kb.nextInt();

                 }while (menuChoice >=0&&menuChoice<12);
```

Answer (score 0):

First you cannot do this (menuChoice != menuChoice);. This will be always false. That's why it runs forever.

So do something like below.

add a variable int , and add a do while like this

`Scanner kb = new Scanner( System.in );

int flag = 1;
do{
// do your things here
Sysout "Enter 2 to exit";
flag = kb.nextInt();

}while(flag != 2)`